# Can I Run Docker Exec from an external VM?

Tags: docker, docker-daemon, docker-exec

I have a group of docker containers running on a host (172.16.0.1). Because of restrictions of the size of the host running the docker containers, I'm trying to set up an auto-test framework on a different host (172.16.0.2). I need my auto-test framework to be able to access the docker containers. I've looked over the docker documentation and I don't see anything that says how to do this.

Is it possible to run a docker exec and point it to the docker host? I was hoping to do something like the following but there isn't an option to specify the host.:

```
docker exec -h 172.16.0.1 -it my_container bash
```

Should I be using a different command?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you describe the broader environment where you need `docker exec`?  I'd generally reserve it for a debugging tool; I'd avoid scripting it, especially in a multi-host environment like what you're describing.

Comment: We are working to set up a development pipeline in an air-gapped environment. The goal is to have Jenkins run Cucumber tests on the services running in docker containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why there is need of doing `docker exec` remotely. But anyways it is achievable.

You need to make sure your docker daemon on your host where your containers are running is [listening on a socket](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option).

Something like this:

```
# Running docker daemon which listens on tcp socket
$ sudo dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
```

Now interact with the docker daemon remotely from external VM using:

```
$ docker -H tcp://<machine-ip>:2375 exec -it my-container bash
OR
$ export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://<machine-ip>:2375"
$ docker exec -it my-container bash
```

***Note:** Exposing docker socket publicly in your network has some serious security risks. Although there are other ways to expose it on [encrypted HTTPS socket](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/) or over the ssh protocol.*

Please go through these docs carefully, before attempting anything:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/

Comment: Anyone who can access the Docker socket this way can **trivially root the host**.  Be incredibly careful about enabling this option.  I'd go for a large-scale overhaul of my test setup to not need `docker exec` before considering this path.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SSH on both machines you can easily execute commands on remote daemon like that:

```sh
docker -H "ssh://username@remote_host" <your normal docker command>
# for example:
docker -H "ssh://username@remote_host" exec ...
docker -H "ssh://username@remote_host" ps
# and so on
```

Another way to do the same is to store `-H` key value into `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable:

```sh
export DOCKER_HOST=ssh://username@remote_host
# now you can talk to remote daemon with your regular commands
# these will be executed on remote host:
docker ps
docker exec ...
```

Without SSH you can make Docker listen for TCP. This will require you to make some preparations to maintain security. [This](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/) guide walks through creating certificates and some basic usage. After that you will have somewhat similar usage:

```sh
docker --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem --tlscert=cert.pem --tlskey=key.pem \
  -H=172.16.0.1:2376
```

At last you can use `docker context` to save external hosts and their configuration. Using context allows you to communicate with various remote hosts with ease by using `--context <name>` option. Read context documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/).